# Cannot correctly retrieve 16-bit integers inside openGL fragment shader

Tags: c++, ios, opengl-es, gpgpu

What I want to do: use signed 16-bit integers inside a fragment shader for GPGPU computation, using openGL ES 2.0 on iOS.

I have verified that I have set up my (input) texture buffer and (output) frame buffer correctly, and can pass 16-bit integers in (by aliasing onto the buffer using an unsigned 8-bit pointer), render the individual bytes to the frame buffer, and retrieve the bytes and reconstruct the correct 16-bit values back on the CPU side.

If I call glClearColor, I can pass in values such as

```
glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5);  // endian-agnostic way to initialize buffer with "no data" values (-32640)
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

I am using the test values of (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5) for glClearColor.  These should be equivalent to passing in -32640 (signed) or 32896 (unsigned).

I can correctly retrieve the values (as the unsigned equivalent) inside the fragment shader as

```
#extension GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch : require

varying highp vec2 vTexCoord;
uniform sampler2D myTexture;

void main()
{
    lowp vec4 myIntArray = texture2D( myTexture, vTexCoord);
    // Retrieve value from frame buffer
    lowp vec4 lastFragColor = gl_LastFragData[0];

    // Recover the value (stored in alpha (high byte) and red (low byte)
    highp float signed_value = lastFragColor.a;
    signed_value = signed_value*255.0*256.0 + lastFragColor.r*255.0;

    //  ... Do stuff with the recovered value.
    // Here, I simply verify value is recovered correctly (as an unsigned int equivalent):

    // This draws the pixel green, indicating success
    if (signed_value >= 32896.0) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
    else {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }

    // But changing the threshold value very slightly (replacing the lines
    // above with those below) draws the pixel red, correctly
    // indicating the condition is not met, because the value is
    // 32896
    if (signed_value >= 32896.01) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
    else {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
}
```

However, I want to pass in an array of different values, so instead of using glClearColor, I set up a buffer, and pass it a pointer to an array of my signed 16-bit integers (basically aliasing onto my signed int16_t bytes as if they were just unsigned bytes.)

I can then render these to the frame buffer, and get the correct values back out, using glReadPixels and aliasing an int16_t pointer to that array back on the CPU.  However, using the same logic as above, but accessing my texture instead of the frame buffer:

```
highp float signed_value = myIntArray.a;
signed_value = value*255.0*256.0 + myIntArray.r*255.0;
```

Using values fro my texture, I can only correctly reconstruct values from 0 to 32767 inside the fragment shader, but not values > 32767.   I need to be able to reconstruct any of the 2^16 possible values, either as signed or unsigned.  Any ideas why I can reconstruct values greater than 32767 from the frame buffer, but not from my texture buffer?

(EDITED TO ADD: Correction - it seems I cannot pass in, render, and retrieve *all* 16 bit ints through my texture... what was coming out before as negative values were artifacts of initializations using glClear().  The negative values I pass in via my texture render as black and are reconstructed on the CPU as zero.  Values between 0 and 32767 inclusive are handled correctly.  So... is it possible to pass in signed int16 values (or unsigned int16 values > 32767) and correctly reconstruct them inside the fragment shader?)

Comment: It might be something weird resulting from mixing float precisions in your calculations. Does it work if you declare everything as highp?

Comment: should the code be this? (changed value to signed_value): signed_value = signed_value*255.0*256.0 + lastFragColor.r*255.0;

Comment: @samgak.  1) Good question... I just tried changing variable `myIntArray` to `highp` - same result.  It's curious that the `lowp` value `lastFragColor` retrieved from `gl_LastFragData`  does work.  I intentionally pulled these input values in both cases (`gl_LastFragData`  and `myIntArray` ) into the `highp` working variable signed_value so that subsequent operations would would maintain precision.  2) yes - typo on var name `signed_value` (edited code to fix) - this was/is correct in running code, though.  Good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the fragment shader code was fine; I was looking in the wrong place.  Unbeknownst to me, the "client" was clamping the inputs to be non-negative.  Mystery solved, albeit with a big slap to the forehead.